# Why 'axios' and $http (vue-resource) behave differently for json query string?

Tags: json, vue.js, axios, vue-resource

I was developing a `vue` app and to fetch data from server i was using `vue-resource`

My code using `vue-resource` was

```
this.$http.get('api/url', {
     params: {
         authData: authData,
         otherData: otherData
     }
})
```

Here the authdata is json string, something like `{"userName":"User+name","id":"userid",....}`

Now for some reasons i have to move to `axios` So i changes my code to

```
axios.get('api/url', {
     params: {
         authData: authData,
         otherData: otherData
     }
})
```

In both cases the data is same but when i see the network call. I got different result.

**In first case** the query string in network call was

```
authData[userName]: 'User+name'
authData[id]    : 'userid'
otherData: 'otherData'
```

**In Second case** the query string in network call was

```
authData: {"userName":"User+name","id":"userid"....}
otherData: 'otherData'
```

Now my question is **why is this happening and how to achieve first format in `axios`.**  I don't want to convert json string to array manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because Axios serializes JavaScript objects to JSON. To serialize in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format you will need to use one of the [techniques described in the Axios documentation](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format).

I think [qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) is a nice solution for you:

```
// Use object shorthand notation if it's supported in your environment
axios.post('/foo', qs.stringify({ authData, otherData }));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Axios** defaults to `application/json` when sending params while **vue-resource** in your case was sending them in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

You could use this function I got from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/lastguest/1fd181a9c9db0550a847) and use it to convert your object to a URL encoded string.

```
function JSON_to_URLEncoded(element, key, list){
  var list = list || [];
  if (typeof(element) == 'object'){
    for (var idx in element)
      JSON_to_URLEncoded(element[idx],key?key+'['+idx+']':idx,list);
  } else {
    list.push(key+'='+encodeURIComponent(element));
  }
  return list.join('&');
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var params = JSON_to_URLEncoded({auth: {username: 'someUser', id: 'someID'}, other: 'other'})
console.log(params)

axios.get('/url?' + params, {
  headers: {
    contentType: 'x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
})
```